# Unable to uncheck server controlled checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have some checkboxes created by the server. Some of these are checked, while others aren't.

I can check and uncheck (with the mouse) the checkboxes that are created unchecked all that I want, but if it was created checked, I can't click it to uncheck it.

The code generating the textboxes:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox chk = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox();
chk.ID = colName; 
chk.AutoPostBack = false;
if (val != null && val != "")
{
    chk.Checked = true;
}
ChecklistPanel.Controls.Add(chk);
```

Though, that shouldn't matter becuase even if I add the controls in the .aspx file and set checked="true" they still behave the same way.

if it helps, here is how the c# decides to render the controls:

```
<div id="uniform-MainContent_EmpMain_dv_access_to" class="checker">
    <span class="checked">
        <input id="MainContent_EmpMain_dv_access_to" class="checked" 
            type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$EmpMain$dv_access_to" style="opacity: 0;">
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: what does the css class `checked` look like?

Comment: You mean that, *using the mouse*, you can't clear its selection?

Comment: correct. i can not clear it with a mouse click.

Comment: can you put your `css-classes` and `html` generated by the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only resion could be the Id of your checkbox.
There should be unique id of every checbox you create.
You can't have multiple controls having same ID.

Comment: can you use firebug to see if any other control coming over that. If any control is overlapping you can not take any action.

Comment: @smarble it can be `div` or `td` or any `html-control` or any `server-control`

Comment: They're in a panel, and that's it. It gets put in a span and a div when it gets rendered.

Comment: The controls may be overlapping. Can you put `css-class` and html rendered in your broser.

Answer (score 0):

Remove style="opacity: 0;
And then try.

Comment: style="opacity: 0;" makes the check box invisible. Change the opacity value and then try.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i guess there was some hidden javascript I did not know about, and that fixed it.